# Fetch API response.json() resulting in SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data

Tags: javascript, json, rest, fetch-api

I am trying to call REST service using fetch() but I keep getting

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

I thought that there is something wrong with JSON my rest service was returning so I tried calling some public REST API (https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1) but I got the same error.
What am I doing wrong?

The code that fails:

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1', {mode: 'no-cors'})
    .then((resp) => resp.json())
    .then((data) => console.log(data));
```

Comment: seems npo errot, i made a demo without cors and works fine https://jsfiddle.net/dnq2osoy/178/, seems is the mode

Comment: Could be a network error on your side or as @ÁlvaroTouzón suggested the response youre getting because of no-cors. I believe its the first though

Comment: removing no-cors works when calling this public api, but when I'm calling my service on localhost without no-cors then I get TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

Comment: it indeed was related to network error and missing headers in responses from my rest service, Thank you all!

Comment: @ŁukaszGruba, it would have been great to let us know what headers were missing in an answer...

Comment: I would like to know the missing headers too!

Comment: Answer is not there regarding the missing headers, that would be very helpful thanks!